# Spring MVC : Multiple buttons with different actions

Tags: spring-mvc, controller

Can we have multiple submit button with different actions?? 
I mean if we have button "Save" and button "Next" each one have it own action to do !
Save have to save the current Model ..
Next have to load the next ModelAttribute on the next page..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `<form>` submit button will invoke the *action* url of that form by default.
You may better want to have two buttons wrapped inside you html content and handle the click event on each one separately either with `oncick` event or with JS (jQuery should be you best friend).

Comment: yes it could be a good way to resolve that, but i've handled it by making those buttons as a link using <a></a> then putting the action "next" that i've declared in spring controller at "href"  that's all :D thank you !!

Comment: Glad to hear that you made it :)